# How to implement generation of combinations in Array in Scala

Tags: arrays, algorithm, scala, combinations

I want Scala codes of a function that, given an array, generates k-combinations of the array.

Consider to generate 3-combinations of an array of 5 elements for example, the function, say `computeNCK`, behaves as follows:

```
computeNCK(Array(1,2,3,4,5),3) = Array(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(1, 2, 4), Array(1, 2, 5), Array(1, 3, 4), Array(1, 3, 5), Array(1, 4, 5), Array(2, 3, 4), Array(2, 3, 5), Array(2, 4, 5), Array(3, 4, 5))
```

The program works similarly to `combinations(n: Int): Iterator[List[A]]` of `List`, but I want deal with `Array`.

Note I am thinking of a code that directly handle `Array`, but not one that first computes in other data type like `List` and converts it to `Array` (using such as `toArray`).

In other words, the program is like an "Array version" of the following Scala code to compute k-combinations.

```
  def computeNCK[A](l:List[A], n: Int): List[List[A]] =
    if (n > l.size) Nil
    else l match {
      case _ :: _ if n == 1 => l.map(List(_))
      case hd :: tl => computeNCK(tl, n - 1).map(hd :: _) ::: computeNCK(tl,n)
      case _ => Nil
  }
```

Comment: `combinations(n: Int)` works for `Array` as well. `Array(1,2,3,4,5).combinations(3)` returns a value of type `Iterator[Array[Int]]`

Comment: No. I need the function to return `Array[Array[Int]]` instead of `Iterator[Array[Int]]`, since `Iterator` has a performance problem in iterating on huge data. Of course, `Array(1,2,3,4,5).combinations(3).toArray` does not work for my purpose for the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use the Array.combinations method?

```
scala> Array("a","b","c", "d").combinations(2).toList
res0: List[Array[String]] = List(Array(a, b), Array(a, c), Array(a, d), Array(b, c), Array(b, d), Array(c, d))
```

Comment: No, it does not work for my purpose. As I wrote in the question, I need to avoid using type conversion like `toList` or `toArray`, since I have to need to scale this function and thus such type conversions make significant performance loss.